# Add clickableItems to Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I wanna add clickableItems to Listview. But my problem is, that my class extands Fragment and i can not do that easily. Additionaly i wanna by clicking the item change the page to another page. My code is:

```
public class MyCoursesFragment extends Fragment  implements OnItemClickListener,    OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = MyCoursesFragment.class.getName();
private ListView listView;
String listItem[]={"Vl1", "VL2"};
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycourses_layout, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.Course);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), DocumentFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", "1");
            listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            FrontPageFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return layout;

}   

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {


}
```

}

can you guys pls help me.

THX

Comment: What do you mean by easily because you are using fragments. Any why are you using two diffrent context getActivity().getBaseContext() and FrontPageFragment.this.startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Change this line because your context is wrong:

```
listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        FrontPageFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
```

You need to start a new activity in the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DocumentFragment.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can to do is set up a callback Interface and control everything from your parent Activity.

Your Activity should implement the interface and your Fragment should call those methods when your View or list item gets clicked.

---

Something along the lines of:

#### interface

```
public interface OnListItemClickCallback {
    public void onListItemShortClick(View view);
    public void onListItemLongClick(View view);
}
```

#### Fragment

```
public MyListFragment extends ListFragment
                      implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {

    private OnListItemClickCallback clickCallback;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // make sure the parent activity implements your interface
        try
        {
            clickCallback = (OnListItemClickCallback) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Parent Activity doesn't implement OnListItemClickCallback");
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnListItemClickCallback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(Bundle b) {
        ...
        getListView().setOnListItemClickListener(this):
        getListView().setOnListItemLongClickListener(this):
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(...) {
        clickCallback.onListItemShortClick(view)
    }

    // same idea for long click if you want it

}
```

#### Activity

```
public MyActivity extends Activity
                  implements OnListItemClickCallback {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onListItemShortClick(View view) {
        // do something like replace your fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemLongClick(View view) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```